# If * means pointing to the adress of a variable, why is e.g (int*)var not pointing to var?

Tags: c++

```cpp
int var = 100;
cout << (int*)var<< endl;
cout << &var<< endl;
```

`(int*)var` printed just 100 in hex, which I don't quite understand.  Can you explain why it is doing so?

I would like to know other ways of pointing to an address without creating a complete new pointer variable.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you think should have been printed, and by what logic?

Comment: `*` doesn't mean "pointing to the adress of a variable"

Comment: `(int*)` just casts `var` to a pointer; it doesn't change its value

Comment: If you are asking, why hex rather than decimal, it's the default for pointers and addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> If * means pointing to the adress of a variable, then...

Does `*` mean "pointing to the adress of a variable" though? What do you think this means?

```
21 * 2
```

`*` means different things in different contexts. In a type name, it means that the type is a pointer. In an expression it is an operator. In case the operator is binary and operands are numbers, it means multiplication. In case the operator is unary and the operand is a pointer, it means indirection through that pointer.

> (int*)var printed just 100 in hex, which I don't quite understand. Can you explain why is it doing so

This is how reinterpreting an integer to a pointer type *typically* works. The value was 100, and the value remained 100 when you reinterpreted it as a pointer.

Strictly speaking, the conversion isn't meaningfully defined for integer types that aren't large enough to represent all pointer values, so converting an `int` doesn't make sense.

> I would like to know other ways of pointing to an adress without creating a complete new pointer variable.

You've shown a way how to do that: `&var`. That creates a pointer object pointing to `var` without creating a pointer variable. Another way to create a pointer prvalue is use `this` keyword in a member function, or call a function that returns a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

What you have just written does not make sense.  First you say:

```
int var = 100;
```

... but then you ***typecast*** *the value* of `var` into *"a pointer to an `int`"*:

```
(int *)var
```

The only reason why it didn't crash-and-burn is that you did not actually try to *use* that pointer to access something in memory.  But, `cout` was smart enough to realize, *"say, the programmer says that this is a pointer."*  So it printed, in hex, *the value* of the pointer itself, not any data that the pointer was supposedly pointing at.

**Just To Be Clear**:

`(int *)var` **does not** mean "point to the address of a variable."  (If you want "the address of something," albeit *not* "a pointer to the same", use `&var`).  Instead, this is just a **typecast**, which in this case means: ***"treat the value of `var`*** as 'a pointer to an int'."